# Question related to pathfinder kinematics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

In the given question I am able to answer that v = 20m/s as in a circle at the diametrically opposite points the direction of velocity will be opposite hence they will add up to give 2v =40m/s hence v=20m/s .

But this means that the car traveling in the circle will take 25s to cover a distance of Rπ hence v= 200 π /25 > 20 so please tell me what am I getting wrong?

To calculate the v=20m/s I considered two particles one going in the east direction and the other going in the west direction along the circle and it can be easily verified that at this instant vi-(-vi)=2vi which is the max possible relative velocity

[image]

Comment: Without knowing the reference positions or checking the answer, how did you calculate v=20 ?

Comment: Ive looked at this and thought about it and have the same issue as you. I even thought about tilting the circle, and I cannot resolve it. (Can only rotate the circle about an axis parallel to the straight road - if we must still end-up with a spot where the relative speed is 0). I see no way around the contradiction. They still max out at 38 and min at 0, giving 19 m/s for the speed of each. Which contradicts the period of 50 seconds to go around the circle, such that v>19. (All as you describe). Suspecting the question is flawed.

Comment: Now I have edited the question